# Using query string redirect to different page on different module in angular6

Tags: html, typescript, routes, angular6

In my application there are multiple modules.One header bar is in different module which is static.On header bar "Products" option is there.But "Products" page is present in different module.Client requirement to use Query string to click on "product" and pass it to "product" page Component which is in different module.Is it possible??And How can pass it to component??

header Bar option-Below www.example.com is common for all application

```
<a href="www.example.com?path=product">Product</a>
```

And product controller-

```
export class productComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use angular-routing, attaching directly the href to the anchor tag will go outside your application, then please share your route module and routes configuration